# PostgreSQL : FOR SHARE & FOR UPDATE priority

Tags: postgresql, locking

Here is my situation:

- I have 2 types of actions A & B, each read or update a single ressource.
- Actions A should be able to be executed concurrently.
- Actions A should wait for Actions B to be finished.
- Actions B should wait for Actions A to be finished.
- Actions B should wait for Actions B to be finished.

This is solved perfectly using FOR SHARE for Actions A, and FOR UPDATE on Actions B

My problem is the following:

- using this model, Actions B can be on hold indefinetely as long as new Actions A are coming through.
- I want that once an Action B is trying to acquire its LOCK, new Action A should be on hold.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: It it necessary that the resource be represented by a row in a table?  AccessShare and AccessExclusive locks on tables already behave the way you want, so you could represent the resource as a dummy table.

Comment: yes, it has to be a row. But wouldn't AccessExclusive have the same problem ? The AccessExclusive will never be granted if AccessShare queries are constantly being executed.

Comment: A pending AccessExclusive blocks incoming AccessShare, and waits for the existing ones to drain away.  Which is very annoying in some cases, and a good thing in others.  Row-level share/update locks don't work that way, presumably due to technical implementation details. Perhaps you can get what you want with the "pg_advisory_xact_lock*" functions, which behave the same way as table locks do.